# Why is non-greedy match consuming entire pattern even when followed by another non-greedy match

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP8, I'm struggling to figure out how to conditionally match some key that may or may not appear in a string.
I would like to match both

```
-----------key=xyz---------------
```

AND

```
--------------------------
```

The dashes("-") could be any non-space character, and only used here for a cleaner to read example.

The regex is matching "key=..." if its containing group is greedy like below.
But this isn't adequate, because the full match will fail a "key=xyz" is missing the subject string.

```
/
(\S*)?                 
(key\=(?<foundkey>[[:alnum:]-]*))
\S*
/x
```

if that  capture group is non-greedy, then the regex just ignores the key match any "key=xyz"

```
/
(\S*)?                 
(key\=(?<foundkey>[[:alnum:]-]*))?
\S*
/x
```

I tried debugging in this [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/OevQk6/1) but couldn't figure it out.

I sorted this out using multiple regexs, but hoping someone can help address my misunderstandings so I learn know how to make this work as a single regex.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```bash
/
^
\S*?
(?:
   key=(?<foundkey>\w+)
   \S*
)?
$
/xm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OevQk6/6)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `\S*?`: Match 0 or more whitespaces non-greedy
- `(?:`: Start Lookahead

  - `key=(?<foundkey>\w+)`: Match `key=` text followed by 1+ word characters as capture group `foundkey`
  - `\S*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `)?`: End lookahead. `?` makes it an optional match
- `$`; End

Comment: This doesn't capture the key when it exists.

Comment: Also `(?:` Starts a non-matching group not a Lookahead.
 I did attempt to use lookbehind to find "tag" while troubleshooting `(?<=` which didn't work either.

Comment: Some more minor updates made. Please refresh the page. There is no need to use any lookahead. We just need an optional non-capture group.

Comment: Oh it looks good  now and makes total sense, thanks!